# Why the integral does not converge?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Why the integral $\int_1^{ + \infty } \frac{dx}{x - 1}$ is not a finite number? I know that when you compute that its infinite but from the looks of the graph it looks like finite, the graph comes very close to $x=1$ and $y=0$, isn't it the same with $0.99999\ldots=1$?

Comment: You're confusing the property of the function having finite integral with the property of the function going to 0 as $x$ goes to $\infty$. These are not the same and, indeed, neither one implies the other.

Comment: The convergence to zero of the integrated function is necessary but not sufficient condition for its integral to converge. Think about discrete infinite series. The same thing happens. The harmonic series diverges ($\sum \frac{1}{n}$), although the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Not close enough.

Consider

$$\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}\frac{dx}{x}.$$

By a rescaling of the variable $z=\epsilon x$, this is

$$I:=\int_1^2\dfrac{dz}{z},$$ a finite quantity, independent of $\epsilon$.

So the integral on

$$\left[\frac1{2^n},1\right]=\left[\frac1{2^n},\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right]\cup \left[\frac1{2^{n-1}},\frac1{2^{n-2}}\right]\cup\cdots\left[\frac1{2},1\right]$$ is $nI$. Even if the slices get thinner and thinner, the height compensates and the total diverges.

Similarly, the integral on

$$[1,2^n]=[1,2]\cup[2,4]\cup\cdots[2^{n-1},2^n]$$ is $nI$. The slices are lower and lower, buth their width compensates.

---

Convergence depends on how fast the quantity decreases to zero.

Comment: Interesting how you deal with both ends with the same argument.